# Is it necessary to show server-side errors in the UI when Formik validation schema is set?

Tags: reactjs, security, formik, yup

I have both client and server side validation in place. Formik & Yup validation schema stop users from submitting values with incorrect format.

Should I still consider rendering server-side errors in my web app in case user somehow manages to bypass client side validation? So, can Formik/Yup validation schema be bypassed on the client side? It seems like there are no native html attributes on inputs, like disabled, that user can simply delete from the DOM.

Comment: You should always adds up server side validations to adds a extra layer of security, If you won't do the same, than user can get into site using tools like Postman. I suggests you to Never depends on client side validations all the time.

Comment: @MaulikPatel I mentioned I already have server side validation for form fields. Please read my question carefully and let me know if anything is unclear.